# Wired logitech mouse and wireless logitech keyboard freeze randomly

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, freeze, logitech, budgie

I've got a problem with my Logitech K400+ keyboard and a wired Logitech mouse B110. These 2 peripherals freeze randomly. I don't know why exactly.

In the beginning I thought that the problem come from my Linux version (Mint 18), but when I reinstalled my computer with a 20.04 version of Mint, the issue was the same. So I told myself, maybe it's the distribution. When I tried with a CentOS 7 live USB, I had the same issue, so I think there is something (hardware?) that's causing this problem.

Before that for about 2 months, I didn't have this issue.

System information:

- ASUS VM40B mini PC with a dual core 1.5 GHz Intel Celeron 1007U processor. It also has 12GB DDR3 RAM, a Kingston 250GB SSD, integrated Intel HD Graphics, 10/100/1000 Mbps Gigabit Ethernet, 802.11ac Wi-Fi, Bluetooth 4.0, HDMI, VGA, S/PDIF, USB 3.0, and USB 2.0 ports.
- My mini PC has only Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 installed.
- Kernel version is 5.4.0-52-generic
- I use one VGA screen and another one on HDMI
- Logitech K400+ keyboard with its unifying receiver
- Wired Logitech mouse B110
- For my work I use an USB Headset Sennheiser and software like Microsoft Teams, AnyDesk or TeamViewer 12 and Zoiper 5 (free version).

The problem is not one of these apps because when I tried a CentOS 7 live USB yesterday, my computer froze again, and none of these apps were installed.

I updated the USB autosuspend with the -1 value thinking it was the problem, but it didn't change anything. Sometimes the computer doesn't freeze during the day, sometimes it freezes two or three times on the following day.

The only solution is to restart the computer.

Something strange I've noticed is if I connect an USB numeric keypad (manufacturer Bluestork), I can use the arrows to change the options and I can choose to shutdown or restart properly, but I can't do anything else.

Today I deactivated the bluetooth, the wifi on my computer (in Linux only) and I disconnected my wired mouse. I don't know if it will change something. Wait and see.

Another strange thing is when I use Teams or Zoiper and my USB headset, if the computer freezes, I can see the speaker in the dashboard moving like I was moving the volume of the sound.

Comment: Hello karel, thanks for your answer. My mini PC have just linux installed. i could publish my syslog file if it could help. I had again this problem this morning just after logging in my session and once again a few minutes later.

Comment: Try installing Psensor (`sudo apt install psensor`) to check if one of your computer's components may be overheating.

Comment: Hello, Ok i'll try it and come back here for the results

Comment: Hello,I've tried psensor and what a surprise when i saw the temperature !

Comment: Hello, I've tried psensor and it showed me thé temperature if m'y SSD Kingston a 400 250GB at 98°C.

Comment: That's way too hot for an SSD, but there's one remaining question. NVMe SSDs run so fast that they automatically self-throttle unless installed with a heatsink and sometimes also require a fan. non-NVMe SSDs do not require either a heatsink or a fan.

Comment: It's not a nvme SSD. So i've réinstaller linux on my ils HDD drive to see and since the reinstallation the pc didn't freeze again at this time. Hope it is the solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've seen a bad HDD before, but I've never seen a bad SSD and this is worrisome to me. Please check the cable to the SSD and make sure that the cable connections to the SSD are secure.

Comment: Hello, I'm agree with toi but my SSD is plugged directly on the SATA connector. There is on cable.

Comment: You gotta figure this out. Maybe have some technician take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have the freezing issue only when I connect my Logintech MX Master 3 mouse by Bluethoose. But, when it connected by unify receiver, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem.
It was the SSD.
Kingston told me to update it with their updater (under Windows,  ).
The SSD didn't want to be updated.
So I decided to replace it.
Since that replacement, I haven’t had any more problems.